# Reading tuples stored in textfile

Tags: python, list, tuples, text-files

I was looking for a way to permanently store tuples created by a python program also after runtime. So I just decided for simplicity to write that data into a textfile (or is there some much more elegant yet simple solution to recommend?)

so the command for doing that looks like:

```
import codecs
txt = codecs.open("data.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    .
    .
    .
data = set1, set2, set3
print >> txt, data
```

resulting in a textfile that looks like

```
(u'name1', 'file1', 'date1')
(u'name2', 'file2', 'date2')
    .
    .
    .
```

what is the correct way to access data.txt only displaying all the second data-sets, in the example case 'file1', 'file2' etc?

I messed around with for loops, read() and readline() but never got to just a simple output of the second item in my file... I hope that someone can help me there?

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As this is tabular data you could also just use `csv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [pickle.dump](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) and [pickle.load](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) to do all the work for you.  That is a reasonable choice if you don't mind the file being in a Python specific format.

Also consider using [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) to store the data. This format is readable by other programs and it is queryable (i.e. you can retrieve just the *filename* field instead of the entire record).

Otherwise, the traditional solution for a reading straight text dump is to read the file line-by-line, either parse or evaluate the text to convert it back into a Python object, and then extract the fields of interest:

```
for line in codecs.open("data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8"):
    tup = ast.literal_eval(line)
    print tup[1]
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. I know decided to make use of python's sqlie3-module and hope for the best :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to save the variables as they are.

Comment: That is helpful advice but doesn't answer his question on how to read the file he has already created.  That still warrants an answer.

Comment: Yep, but I agree with the code you wrote in your edit, so I will not write a duplicate.

Comment: Fair enough.  Maybe the two answers will make it clear that reinventing special purpose file formats isn't the way to go :-)

Comment: I was planning to store this data as simple as possible as well as versatile enough to be later accessed and processed by python or php. Formerly I have used for example mysql to do that but found that a way to heavy application to do those simple tasks.... I just used the txt-file method for testing purposes and might look into the pickle module... yet someone yesterday mentioned shelves as well... I do not want to reinvent file formats in the end... so I will look into what python has to offer on a small-scale db-alike basis, thanks a lot!